# How to send to RabbitMQ with escape character

Tags: java, rabbitmq

i am pushing to rabbitMq like this

```
@PostMapping(value = {"/push"},produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
     public ResponseEntity<String> push(
            @RequestBody String payload,
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse,HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) {
        rabbitMQPublisherService.send(payload);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }



@Service
public class RabbitMQPublisherService {

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    @Value("${rabbitmq.queue}")
    private String queue;

    public void send(String message) {

        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(queue,new String(message.getBytes()));
    }
}


@Configuration
public class RabbitMQConfiguration {

    @Value("${rabbitmq.queue}")
    private String queueName;

    @Value("${rabbitmq.exchange}")
    private String exchange;

    @Value("${rabbitmq.routingkey}")
    private String routingKey;

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return new Queue(queueName, false);
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectExchange exchange() {
        return new DirectExchange(exchange);
    }

    @Bean
    public Binding binding() {
        return BindingBuilder.bind(queue()).to(exchange()).with(routingKey);
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    @Bean
    public AmqpTemplate rabbitTemplate(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {
        final RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory);
        rabbitTemplate.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        return rabbitTemplate;
    }
}
```

But everytime, i push a jason it pushes in the queue with escape characters , i dont want excape cahracters . Suggest me in this regard

Output

> "{\n\"check\": \"1\",\n\"type\": \"1212\"\n}"

Desired OutPut

> "{"check": "1","type": "1212"}"

Comment: Do you really need to use the `Jackson2JsonMessageConverter` to post the string-bytes?

Comment: even if we remove the converter the output is same

Answer (score 0):

Your desired output is not a valid string. It contains double quotes that must be escaped as `\"`.

The newlines `\n` are only whitespace and can be ignored.

The output is a string that contains this JSON object:

```
{
    "check": "1",
    "type": "1212"
}
```

This is exactly what you expect.